# Preventing empty app process under Android

Tags: android

I am porting an existing Windows 8 / iOS app to Android.

Of course, I want to re-use as much of the program logic / control flow as possible.
Unfortunately, Android has this strange concept of Activities.
(I only use one single activity because the app is a game.)

The problem I have is the following:

- Static variables are not bound to the activity lifetime but to the process lifetime.
- My activity can be destroyed while the process is still alive. (be it through configuration change or due to low memory)
- But I have to be sure that a newly created activity gets "fresh" static variables.

I could solve the problem by

- preventing activity restarts due to configuration changes (that's fine with be because I do not use layouts or size-dependent resources)

AND at the same time

- assuring that when the activity is destroyed (e.g. user switches to another app, memory low), the whole process will be destroyed, too.

The later one is my question: How do I make sure that the app process is killed whenever there are no activities alive? (In my understanding, it is not impossible, unfortunately, that empty processes exist)

Comment: "My activity can be destroyed while the process is still alive. (be it through configuration change or due to low memory)" -- yes to the configuration change part. No to the low-memory part. Your whole process may be terminated due to low memory, but not individual activities. "assuring that when the activity is destroyed (e.g. user switches to another app" -- activities are not destroyed when the user switches to another app. "How do I make sure that the app process is killed whenever there are no activities alive?" -- that is not needed in a well-written app.

Comment: What you are trying to say is either don't use static variables, or else make sure that activity (re)creation reinitializes them.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Are you saying that in case of low memory, always the whole process is killed? But what if the user presses the Back button? Then, is it possible that only the activity but not the whole process is killed? I have read of "empty proesses" (processes with no activities). When can they occur? Or asking differently: Does the problem I am afraid of, exist? (Can the process live while the only activity has been destroyed?)

Comment: @eikuh: "Are you saying that in case of low memory, always the whole process is killed?" -- correct. "But what if the user presses the Back button?" -- the default behavior of BACK destroys the current activity and returns control to the preceding activity. This does not terminate the process. "Then, is it possible that only the activity but not the whole process is killed?" -- yes. However, you are welcome to reset your static data members in `onDestroy()` of the activity. Or, better yet, use better programming practices and reduce/eliminate the static data members.

Comment: @Chris Stratton: If I was writing the app from scratch, this would be the right direction. But in my case, the app code already exists. Of course, if there is no easy solution, I have to search for all static variables and initialize them whenever the activity is (re)created.

Comment: Yes, basically you will have to do that.

Comment: @CommonsWare: "However, you are welcome to reset your static data members in onDestroy() of the activity." Yeah sure. The problem is that the static variables are not only in the activity class but also in many other classes. This will mean, I have a lot of work.

Comment: What about killing the process whenever the activity is destroyed?

Comment: "This will mean, I have a lot of work" -- you were the one who decided to use lots of globals/statics. I'd be stunned and disappointed if Windows Phone and/or iOS encouraged global state this way. ["Global Variables Considered Harmful"](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=953355) was published in **1973**. See also http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesConsideredHarmful, http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil

Comment: @CommonsWare: Well, what I wanted to say is rather: "I have some static variables which can be in any class, so I have to check everything". I am aware of the disadvantages of static/global variables. When the advantages were higher (in my opinion) then I used them. I did not know that Android would add another disadvantage… Anyhow, thank you very much for your facts about when processes are killed and when not!